# Application Load balancer for Service Segmentation Using Subdomains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Currently, I am doing service segmentation using subdomains in an existing application.

```
For example:

www.example.com -> static website delivered from s3
admin.example.com -> ELB1 to ec2 group 1
accounts.example.com -> ELB2 to ec2 group 2
search.example.com -> ELB3 to ec2 group 3
```

You can see that I need 3 ELB to achieve this. With the new Application load balancer, I am hoping to do this on 1 load balancer using routing rules.

```
For example :

www.example.com -> static website delivered from s3
admin.example.com -> ELB1 to ec2 group 1
accounts.example.com -> ELB1 to ec2 group 2
search.example.com -> ELB1 to ec2 group 3
```

I cannot rewrite my application to do this. I am hoping to achieve this with routing rules on the application load balancer.

I am aware that I can specify rules for the part after the domain. Can I specify rules for the subdomain?

Already read: https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx3RG2S7V2LM4Y2/Introducing-Application-Load-Balancer-Unlocking-and-Optimizing-Architectures

Comment: Asked on the official AWS thread [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=237165)

Comment: @JyotmanSingh They have started supporting host based routing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news, AWS has started supporting host based routing.

Source:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/04/elastic-load-balancing-adds-support-for-host-based-routing-and-increased-rules-on-its-application-load-balancer/

Answer (score 1):

You can have host based routing now.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything not in OP's self-answer from a week ago, and is extremely bare in itself.

Answer (score 0):

The create-rule documentation indicates that "path-pattern" is currently the only possible field on which a rule can be based:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/create-rule.html

That suggests that "host" or similarly named field providing access to the subdomain is not an option for routing.

However, if the applications on ec groups 1 2 and 3 can support being deployed on arbitrary paths as well as domains, then a new application domain, say, app.example.com, could be created that routed /admin to ec group 1, /accounts to ec group 2, and /search to ec group 3 using an ALB, and the existing subdomains could be told to 301 redirect to their respective new domain + route (admin.example.com -> 301 to app.example.com/admin, etc).

Comment: yes, that seems correct. but i can't modify apps

Comment: In other words, applications cannot run on non-root routes?

Comment: No. it requires additional work and changing URL of the existing site might affect traffic and SEO. I am not willing to take a risk.